# How to pass inputs to a dynamic query in Oracle SQL?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I am trying to create a function that dynamically runs a query based on inputs. The first input for the function, input_id, is the argument for the dynamic query. The second input, IN_QUERY_ID, specifies which query to use.

```
create or replace  
FUNCTION getResultID(  
INPUT_ID NUMBER,  
IN_QUERY_ID NUMBER  
)  
RETURN VARCHAR2  
AS  
 RESULT_ID VARCHAR2(256);  
 query_str VARCHAR2(256);  
 BEGIN  
  select CONSTRUCTOR INTO query_str from query_str_ref     
   where QUERY_ID=IN_QUERY_ID;  
  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE query_str INTO RESULT_ID  USING INPUT_ID;  
   RETURN Result_ID;  
END getResultID;
```

I'm getting an error that I'm not properly ending the statement after "RESULT_ID=IN_QUERY_ID;" I'm wondering if I'm missing some other step.

Comment: please, `DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(INPUT_ID);` and `DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(query_str);`

Comment: Sebas, I put those output lines after " where QUERY_ID=IN_QUERY_ID" and now it is saying that I'm not properly ending the statement after the output lines.  It seems to always find the error before "execute immediate".

Comment: please, comment the execute immediate so you can get the buffer output

Comment: Where are you running this? It seems to be fine in SQL*Plus and SQL Developer; it looks like whatever client you're using doesn't understand the `execute` command, which is strange.

Comment: Sebas, 
INPUT_ID, query_str, IN_QUERY_ID from DBMS_Output:  
20878  
select FIRST_NAME||LAST_NAME||to_char(BIRTH_DATE,'yyyy/mm/dd') as  HOST_ID  FROM INPUT_DATA_TABLE WHERE INPUT_ID=NEW:INPUT_ID;
20

Comment: OK I thought you were getting the error compiling the function, clearly not. Which means it's erroring on the dynamic SQL you're executing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The good news is that it's not your function that's wrong. According to the `dbms_output` that @sebas encouraged you to produce, the string you're trying to execute dynamically is:

```
select FIRST_NAME||LAST_NAME||to_char(BIRTH_DATE,'yyyy/mm/dd') as HOST_ID FROM INPUT_DATA_TABLE WHERE INPUT_ID=NEW:INPUT_ID;
```

There are two thing wrong with that. The `NEW:INPUT_ID` is causing the `ORA-00933`, because the `NEW` looks spurious; if you remove that it will recognise the `:INPUT_ID` as a bind variable. (`NEW` looks like it's come from a trigger but is probably a coincidence). And you should not have a trailing `;` on the string, `execute` doesn't need it and it will break with an invalid character error.

So it should work if the `query_str_ref` entry is changed to:

```
select FIRST_NAME||LAST_NAME||to_char(BIRTH_DATE,'yyyy/mm/dd') as HOST_ID FROM INPUT_DATA_TABLE WHERE INPUT_ID=:INPUT_ID
```

Comment: Yes! This helped! Plus changing :INPUT_ID to :strINPUT_ID.

Answer (score 3):

You haven't declared `Result_ID` as a variable in the function.

Comment: Sorry...I changed the name of the variables in my program for this post for clarity . I did declare result_id.  Do you know what else could be the problem?